# Почему файл _general.sass не видит переменные и миксины?

Tags: html, css, frontend, sass

Файл general.sass не видит миксины в файле _mixins.sass и переменные в файле _variables.sass, но при этом медиа файлы в _media.sass он видит. Как это исправить?[image: файл style.sass]

[image: файл _mixins.sass]

[image: файл _general.sass c ошибкой]

[image: настройки коалы для файла _general.sass]

Answer (score 0):

нужно добавить путь если variables находится в папке а не лежит напрямую

@import "(название папки или ...)/variables"